# Как задать null в QVariantHash?

Tags: c++, sql, база-данных, qt

Требуется записать `null`, не как строку или число в `QVariantHash`, для последующей записи в БД, возможно ли как-то это сделать?
На данный момент, могу задать значение через файл, что и делаю, при этом значение пишется как *"недоступно"*, но иногда возникает потребность записывать это через код, есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: Если поле в БД, например, целое, то так `QVariant(QVariant::Int)`

Answer (score 0):

Удалось получить решение, для этого требуется в QVariantHash записать QJsonValue::Null